# Install numpy in Pyspark Docker container to run on Kubernetes cluster

Tags: python, docker, apache-spark, kubernetes, pyspark

I am trying to run a Pyspark ML pipeline in a Kubernetes cluster, but I get the following exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/spark-af19633f-f439-4c2b-80cc-7a945895b880/main_kubernetes.py", line 1, in <module>
    from jobs.evaluation.evaluator import Evaluator
  File "/tmp/spark-af19633f-f439-4c2b-80cc-7a945895b880/jobs.zip/jobs/evaluation/evaluator.py", line 1, in <module>
  File "/opt/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/ml/__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
  File "/opt/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/ml/base.py", line 25, in <module>
  File "/opt/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/ml/param/__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'
```

for the following import in one of my jobs:

```
from pyspark.ml.evaluation import BinaryClassificationEvaluator, MulticlassClassificationEvaluator
```

I tried to include numpy in the Pyspark Dockerfile like so, but it does not resolve the issue:

```
ARG base_img=spark-base:latest

FROM $base_img
WORKDIR /

# Reset to root to run installation tasks
USER 0

RUN mkdir ${SPARK_HOME}/python
# RUN mkdir /py_files
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt install -y python3 python3-pip && \
    pip3 install --upgrade pip setuptools && \ 
    pip3 install numpy && \
    # Removed the .cache to save space
    rm -r /root/.cache && rm -rf /var/cache/apt/*

COPY python/pyspark ${SPARK_HOME}/python/pyspark
COPY python/lib ${SPARK_HOME}/python/lib
# COPY /python/py_files /py_files
COPY /python/py_files /opt/spark/work-dir/py_files
RUN chmod -R 777 /opt/spark/work-dir/py_files

WORKDIR /opt/spark/work-dir
ENTRYPOINT [ "/opt/entrypoint.sh" ]
# ENTRYPOINT [ "/bin/sh" ]

# Specify the User that the actual main process will run as
# ARG spark_uid=8262567
ARG spark_uid=185
USER ${spark_uid}
```

Is there another way to include numpy?

EDIT:
If I ssh into the container and run the spark job inside it, it doesn't throw an exception and I manually verified, that numpy is indeed installed. So the problem only occurs in Kubernetes.

Comment: Does the base image already have Python already installed ? I mean your "pip3" maybe uses a different python version than the one used by PySpark (It's just a suggestion)

Comment: Hi Flo, thanks for the suggestion! The base image does not include a python installation.